# Start AWS S3 Multipart Upload Java Before Whole File Complete

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The problem that I am having is that I am generating a large JSON Object to upload to S3 which is causing memory issues.

When I attempt to translate the JSON object to a string so that I can get the byte array for GZIP the ECS instance that I am on never finishes.

What I was hoping to do was as I process part of the larger JSON object list array I could take that part upload it, then wait for the next part to be ready and upload it, so on and so forth.

Is this even possible?  I know that if I could get the final file I could break it up, but at this point I can not even do that.

Comment: You could write it to a temporary file and upload that.

Comment: How large is the JSON object?